# Changing the length of Text fields in an Access linked table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, csv

I am exporting a file from a system as `.csv.` My aim is to link to this file as a table (which matches the output field for field) and then run the queries and export.

The problem I am having is that, upon import, all the fields are 255 bytes wide rather than what they need to be.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- I've looked at `ALTER TABLE` but I cannot run multiple `ALTER TABLE` statements in one macro.
- I've also tried appending the table into another table with the correct structure but it seems to overwrite the structure.
- I've also tried using the `Left` function with the appropriate field length, but when I try to export, I pretty much just see 5 bytes per column.

What I would like is a suggestion as to what is the best path to take given my situation. I am not able to amend the initial `.csv` export, and I would like to avoid VBA if possible, as I am not at all familiar with it.

Comment: When you say that "all the fields are 255 bytes wide" what exactly do you mean? Is it that the data values in the text fields are right-padded with spaces to a length of 255 characters? Or do you mean that when you open the linked table in Design View the (maximum) length of the Text fields is 255?

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to worry about the size of `Text` fields in an Access linked table that is connected to a CSV file. Access simply assigns each `Text` field the largest possible *maximum size*: 255. It does not mean that every value is actually 255 characters long, it just means that any values in those fields can be *at most* 255 characters long.

Even if you could change the structure of the linked table (which you can't), it wouldn't make any real difference except to possibly truncate longer `Text` values, and you could easily do that with a String function. For example, if a particular field had to be restricted to 15 characters then you could simply use `Left([fieldName], 15)` as a query column or as the control source in a report.

Comment: In terms of your first paragraph I am aware of that but thanks for the confirmation.

As per my question though I did try using the Left function but when I try to export as fixed width all the columns are restricted to 5 bytes width regardless of what what was in my query.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, as the data set is not that large, I have set this up to append from my source data into a table with the correct structure. I can now run my processes against this table as per normal.